# 403 Forbidden on specific promo form POST contents

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm getting 403 Forbidden responses when attempting to save changes to an existing shopping cart price rule. It *only* occurs under the following condition:

- Adding more than 3 conditions to the rule

For context, I'm trying to add 5 conditions to the rule, all of them structured as:

```
ANY = TRUE:
  IF FOUND WITH ANY = TRUE:
    SKU = X
    SKU = X
    SKU = X
```

If I try to add a fourth `SKU = X` condition and save the rule, I get a 403 forbidden error.

What I know:

- This can only be re-produced on production (not dev/staging)
- I can successfully set 3 or less `SKU = X` conditions with any values
- I can successfully add any other types of conditions with any values
- This occurs before `preDispatch`, so no redirects/forwarding is involved
- The `/.htaccess` file is essentially stock (no rewrites)

Anybody experience this or something similar before?

Comment: I can only say that I have faced with problems with adding big tree conditions. And it was look like something gone wrong (options were not saved, some of them were missed). (that was happened on clean magento). I didn't see into the problem, I just deleted existing rule, and created new one.

Comment: @zhartaunik Your advice gave me hope, but no fortune :) I created the rule from scratch with the same data, including my 4th and 5th conditions, and I got the same error. If I have only 3 conditions, it saves successfully.

Comment: Does your server have any uncommon modifications, such as using mod_security?

Comment: Good question, it looks like that *could* be the case, but I have limited access to the production server (sub-contracted dev) and can't stat the web server config. I can see mod_security.conf but can't confirm it's being used. I'll look into it. Thanks @Agop.

Comment: How about adding the condition directly in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. @Agop had the right idea to investigating mod_security settings. In my case, I wasn't able to control them, and had to defer to the hosting provider.

As it turns out, the host (Nexcess), may have some tight security settings. They even allude to this in their own blog from a few years ago:

> https://blog.nexcess.net/2012/09/14/mod_security-and-content-management-systems/

By tweaking some settings for the account the 403 errors go away (I wasn't able to know *what* settings -- if I do find out I'll post them here).