# 403 forbidden on magento admin category url

Tags: category

I am getting the below error on the admin category index page.

**You don't have permission to access /index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/24a39b3ae8b57eb5a73ab617d8de3be3/ on this server.**

Tried the folder file permission thing but that is all set properly.

Took the site to debug mode but nothing specific.

Can anyone help how to start debugging this one. note only category url is breaking and everyone else is working in admin area. frontend is also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem only in production environments. Turned out to be some recent changes by the hosting provider to tighten `mod_security` rules. Only specific URLs would trigger the error. Here's the question I posed about it:

> [403 Forbidden on specific promo form POST contents](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/67200/1834)

In my case, the `POST` data contained things that were "suspicious," and so resulted in a 403 by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I was able to resolve it by updating system-wide file permissions after unzipping/extracting the .zip or .tar.gz file. Log in via SSH, and make sure you're in the root directory of your Magento instance.

```
find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has now resolved.

There was some firewall issue on the server. The server guys fixed it. No changes were required at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mod Security Tools in WHM, Just see your issue logged over there and un-check the rule and restart the Apache.
If using C PANEL ask your server admin to fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

There were recent changes made to mod_security from my web host.

I contacted them about the issue I was having and they made some configuration changes, and it's now working again.